# React Native componentWillMount / componentDidMount not going triggered after pop navigating and navigate again

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am new in React Native ...just want ask nub question, my App wont triggered componentWillMount and componentDidMount when navigate back to other page,
I use `react-native-router-flux` for navigator

```
componentWillMount() {
 this.props.searchRequest();
}
```

exp: I have homescreen and categories, from home I want go to categories: on categories I have that code, but sometime when I back to previouse page (homescreen) and back again on categories componentWillMount not triggered sometime,

I think my categories scene not unmounted

Comment: Have you tried interaction manager?

Comment: Please post [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us debug your issue.

Comment: just like this issue [link](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/264) ,still got nothing ... @RRikesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can detect props change with

> componentWillReceiveProps()

but we need set state to accommodate new props value,